# redirect admin to /back admin panel after login in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have configured auth to multi auth one is users table and another one is admins table and i did some changes both of tables have their own login separately when i logged in on user login page then will redirect me to admin panel the path is /back and i want for both case admin and user login should redirect me to admin panel same path means after logged in on admin login page redirect me to admin panel to same /back path please help.

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'back','middleware'=>'auth'],function(){
        Route::get('/', 'Admin\DashboardController@index');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::prefix('admins')->group(function() {


Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admins.login');

Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');

Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admins');

});
```

**Auth/AdminLoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('guest:admin'); 

    }


    public function showLoginForm()
    {


        return view('auth.admin-login');

    }


    public function login(Request $request)
    {

         $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
      ]);


         if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {

        return redirect()->intended(route('admins')); 
      }



        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }


}
```